# Can you do a Docker build on another Docker context?

Tags: docker

I know I can use `docker context` to run images, but I was wondering, is it possible to do a `docker build` on a different context so I can leverage faster machines than my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does this by default if you have activated the context.

Here is how I tested this:

First, I created a context which logs into a server over SSH

```
docker context create \                                   
    --docker host=ssh://xxxxx@yy.yy.yy.yy \
    --description="Remote engine" \
    my-remote-engine
```

(Note: the remote user must have access to the docker socket. If you do not, you will get a strange error like `ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at http://docker.example.com. Is the docker daemon running?`)

Then, I activated the context.

```
docker context use my-remote-engine
```

Then, I wrote a short Dockerfile to check which computer it was running on by printing the IP address of the host. I ran it like this.

```
docker build .
```

It displayed the IP address of the remote host.